# How do you iterate (using purrr in R) by passing multiple arguments to BinomCI()

Tags: r, tidyverse

I can calculate individual binomial confidence levels using the following function.

```
library(DescTools)
BinomCI(78, 600, sides = "two.sided",
        conf.level = 0.95, method = "wald") 

#>      est    lwr.ci    upr.ci
#> [1,] 0.13 0.1030906 0.1569094
```

What I want to do is to iterate through DescTools with different values for the arguments `conf.level` and `method`. I can create all the combinations of these arguments that I would like to run using `expand.grid`.

```
conf.level <- c(0.95, 0.99)
method <- c("wald", "wilson", "clopper-pearson")

parameters <- expand.grid(conf.level = conf.level,
                          method = method)
```

However, when I try to use map2 to iterate over the function `BinomCI()`, I get the error message below. Is this because the argument `method` needs a specific input format?

```
map2(parameters$conf.level, parameters$method, ~ BinomCI(78, 600, sides = "two.sided",
                                                         conf.level = .x, method = .y))

# Error in match.arg(arg = method, choices = c("wilson", "wald", "wilsoncc", : 'arg' must be NULL or a 
# character vector
```

I don't think it seems to be a problem with my usage of `map2` itself? Any insight or alternative suggestions is greatly appreciated.

```
# test a random function that takes two arguments 
paste_vars <- function(x, y) {
  paste(x, y)
}

map2(parameters$conf.level, parameters$method, ~ paste_vars(.x, .y)) # this works
```

Comment: After expand.grid, 'method' is a factor, and needs to be turned into a character. `parameters$method <- as.character(parameters$method)`. You can also add the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to expand.grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using BinomCI's internal recycling logic?

```
library(DescTools)
BinomCI(78, 600, sides = "two.sided",
        conf.level = rep(c(0.95, 0.99), each=3), 
        method = c("wald", "wilson", "clopper-pearson"))
```

Resulting in:

```
                    est     lwr.ci    upr.ci
0.95:wald            0.13 0.10309062 0.1569094
0.95:wilson          0.13 0.10542710 0.1592806
0.95:clopper-pearson 0.13 0.10413275 0.1595719
0.99:wald            0.13 0.09463507 0.1653649
0.99:wilson          0.13 0.09864373 0.1694498
0.99:clopper-pearson 0.13 0.09686711 0.1691624
```